# Should I drop duplicates or not?

Tags: machine-learning, data-cleaning, multiclass-classification

I am dealing with a real-data multiclass classification problem. The task is to classify the kind of fault for some equipments.

Features in input are equipments' alarms (X), the target is the fault class (y). For each sample, in addition to alarms, the equipment's ID as long as Timestamp when sample was collected are reported. Note that these two features will not be used for prediction. Original data is made out of 1000 samples.

My idea was to remove duplicates before training a predictive model. Hence, i dropped 50 samples for which values of X, ID, Timestamp and y were identical. But then I realized that considering only X and y the number of duplicates to drop increase to 450. So, I am pretty sure that the "first drop" (removing identical rows) is correct, but I am not sure whether to drop or not all the other sample with the "second drop".

As i told you, the data are from real world and (at least for now) ID and Timestamp are not part of features used for prediction.

Here it is a sample of my data (ID and Timestamp are not displayed):

```
X1   X2   X3   ...   X100   Y
1    0    1    ...   1      2
1    1    0    ...   0      3
1    0    1    ...   1      2
...  ...  ...  ...   ...    ...
0    1    1          1      1
```

Shold i drop duplicates or not, in this specific case?

Comment: Could yo poset a sample of your data, say three rows?

Comment: @sconfluentus I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I drop duplicates or not, in this specific case?

**Yes,** it is like oversampling your data.

The model will be biased towards the duplicated Class although it has no new information.

In the best case, it will not harm but it will never help.